Using a N-channel JFET as a current source
I have used the BF256 (N-channel JFET) many times as a current source, but it is a through hole component and I prefer to use SMD.
I found a few documents on the internet that all list other dynasaurs in TO92 package but I cannot find anything in SOT23.
It is a lengthy process to find an NJF component, find a model line and run a simulation with the gate shorted to the source, to find the bias current.
The "Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current" mentioned in the datasheet is not listed in the .model line and I also cannot find it in parametric search engines. When I search for "depletion" and "SMD" on Mouser there are still 106 MOSFETs listed.

Is there an easier way to find the current of a NJF, Is there a parameter in the .model line that can be used to calculate the current without drawing the schematic?

I know that I can create a current source in many ways but I prefer to use a single cheap N-channel component (without the addition of a resistor).

J202 springs to mind. J111, 112 and 113 are also available in SMD but, asking for product recommendations is off-topic.

A parametric search at mouser yields a lot of results.

Idss is not typically  a well controlled parameter. From 6 to 13mA on the BF256, and similar parts such as MMBF5485/6 have a range of 4 to 10 mA or 8 to 20mA. I think you're going to have to read datasheets.

You can also try looking for depletion-mode MOSFETs. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/transistors/fets-mosfets/single-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoGwAwyqAxlALgJwK4FMA0IA9lANogDMA7ABwCc9IAugQA5pQgDKmAlgHYBzEAF8CtAKy0kIVJEy4CxSGXLlqcAEwAWJq3aQuvQSOHCgA

A thread on the maker.pro forums suggests
$$  I_{drain} = {BETA \; (1 + LAMBDA \; V_{ds})\;(V_{gs} - VTO)^2 } $$
I would rather trust the data sheet than a SPICE model for figuring out \$I_{DSS}\$.

@qrk,
I agree with you that we better trust the datasheet but the formula gives me an idea what MOSFETs to investigate. Instead of looking up all 1000+ that are in the LTspice file "standard.jft".
I have created a macro in Excel to read the standard.jft file and calculated the IDSS (for a Vds of 20V).
This is the list starting with 1mA ordered by current:

For anyone who needs a list like that, this is the VBA macro:
Option Explicit

Private Const FILENAME = "V:\AAA\JFET\standard.jft"
Private Const URL = "https://eu.mouser.com/c/?q=COMPONENT"
Private Const SHEET = "Sheet1"

Sub ReadJFETs()
    Dim F As Integer, lRow As Long, i As Integer, sLine As String, sName As String
    Dim arr1() As String, arr2() As String, arr3() As String
    F = FreeFile
    lRow = 1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear ' !!! clear the entire content of the sheet !!!
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1).Value = "Component"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = "BETA"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 3).Value = "LAMBDA"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 4).Value = "VTO"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 5).Value = "IDSS"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 6).Value = "URL"
    Open FILENAME For Input As #F
    Do While Not EOF(F)
       Line Input #F, sLine
       sLine = Replace(sLine, vbTab, " ")
       If UCase(Left(sLine, 6)) = ".MODEL" Then ' isolate .model lines
          arr1 = Split(sLine, "(")
          arr2 = Split(arr1(LBound(arr1)), " ")
          If UCase(arr2(LBound(arr2) + 2)) = "NJF" Then ' filter NJF types
             lRow = lRow + 1
             sName = arr2(LBound(arr2) + 1)
             If InStr(sLine, "(") > 0 Then
                arr2 = Split(arr1(LBound(arr1) + 1), " ")
             Else
                arr2 = Split(Mid(sLine, InStr(1, sLine, " NJF ", vbTextCompare)), " ")
             End If
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 1).Value = sName
             For i = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
                 If Trim(arr2(i)) <> "" Then
                    arr3 = Split(arr2(i), "=")
                    If Trim(UCase(arr3(LBound(arr3)))) = "BETA" Then
                       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Trim(arr3(UBound(arr3)))
                       ProcessValue lRow, 2
                    End If
                    If Trim(UCase(arr3(LBound(arr3)))) = "LAMBDA" Then
                       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Trim(arr3(UBound(arr3)))
                       ProcessValue lRow, 3
                    End If
                    If Trim(UCase(arr3(LBound(arr3)))) = "VTO" Then
                       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Trim(arr3(UBound(arr3)))
                       ProcessValue lRow, 4
                    End If
                 End If
             Next i
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 5).Formula = "=B" & lRow & "*(1+C" & lRow & "*20)*(0-D" & lRow & ")^2"
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, 6).Value = "=Hyperlink(""" & Replace(URL, "COMPONENT", sName) & """)"
          End If
       End If
    Loop
    Close #F
End Sub
Private Sub ProcessValue(lRow, iCol)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, iCol)
        If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then
           '====================================
           ' dutch regional settings for numbers
           .Value = Replace(.Value, ".", ",")
           '====================================
           Select Case LCase(Right(.Value, 1))
             Case "m"
                .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) / 1000
             Case "u"
                .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) / 1000000
             Case "n"
                .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) / 1000000000
             Case "p"
                .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) / 1000000000000#
             Case "f"
                .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1) / 1E+15
           End Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Just drop it in a module, modify the three constants at the top, and start ReadJFETs

Nice work, thanks for sharing your script.
